# int socket response is not shown by nc

Tags: kotlin, tcp, netty

I'm running a simple tcp server at port 8080 with Netty that responds with `hello` when a connection is made.

```
class MyHandler : ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {

    override fun channelActive(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext) {
        val time = ctx.alloc().buffer(4)
        time.writeBytes("hello".toByteArray())
        val future = ctx.writeAndFlush(time)
        future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE)
    }

}
```

If I run `nc localhost 8080`, I get `hello` response. Everything ok. But when I change my code to respond with `1234` (integer) instead, I get an empty response from `nc`.

```
class MyHandler : ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {

    override fun channelActive(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext) {
        val time = ctx.alloc().buffer(4)
        time.writeInt(1234) // <-- this is the change
        val future = ctx.writeAndFlush(time)
        future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nc` program has no idea that you are sending an integer. So when it receives it, it has no idea what would be an appropriate way to display it.

If you were expecting to literally see "1234", then you were expecting magic. How could `nc` know that the data it received was an encoded integer? If you're going to implement a protocol to send data over TCP, you have to implement it on *both* ends or you will get garbage on the end that doesn't understand the protocol.